# Why did Vinda and Anuvinda share Avanti?

Tags: mahabharata, kings

As I know, Vinda and Anuvinda were the kings of Avanti, they were defeated by Sahadeva in their Digvijaya, they supported the Kauravas and they were finally killed by Arjuna on the 14th.

My question is, why did they share Avanti? This is not normally done, but why were Vinda and Anuvinda the exception?